# GO: error while importing my go file

Tags: go, import, gopath, goland

This is the project structure

```
   /bruteforce
   --/src
   ----/services
   ------/bruteforce.go
   ----/start
   ------/workergenerator.go
```

In bruteforce.go i used "package services", and in workergenerator.go "package main".
Now, i wrote a simple function in bruteforce.go, so in workergenerator.go i imported services package and called this function. This is the problem:

> src/start/workergenerator.go:17:2: imported and not used: "services"
>   src/start/workergenerator.go:26:5: undefined: bruteforce

As you can see, the package is imported well, but the function is not defined (?)

I added to the GOPATH the main folder of my project

> /Users/simon/GolandProjects/bruteforce

Why does the compiler cause this error?

Comment: Please read How to write Go Code (https://golang.org/doc/code.html) now and stick to it. The error messages should be pretty self explanatory.

Comment: It's actually not correct. The user is trying to run ` go run ` on a single file instead of ` go build ` on the directory.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of "[rand package error in Go](//stackoverflow.com/q/8231573/90527)", but question is too unclear due to lack of [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to `Run | Edit Configurations...`, select the run configuration you have and then change the Run Kind from `File` to `Package` and use `start` for the `Package Name`

Comment: Dude, Something so simple. I was beating my head against my compiler trying to figure out why. It's always worked on every other Go program. Don't know why it got flipped for this one. Thank you!